# How to assign an overridden parent class function as a callback function in python subclass

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class Process(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, callback):
        if obj and hasattr(callback, 'im_self') and callback.im_self is obj:
            self.obj = obj
            self.callback=callback.im_func.__name__
        else:
            raise Exception('invalid callback')

class A(object):
    def parse(self):
        print 'in parse()'
        return Process(self, callback=self.test)

    def test(self):
        print 'in class A'

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print 'in class B'
        # do something...
        return Process(self, callback=super(B, self).test)

b=B()

p=b.parse()
callback = getattr(p.obj, str(p.callback))
p=callback()
callback = getattr(p.obj, str(p.callback))
callback()
```

output of the program:

```
in parse()
in class B
in class B
```

doesn't call A.test()

I am using `Scrapy`, it use this way in Process() to save callback function. How to call A.test() through B.test()?

*Update due to comments*
You are right. Both A and B are spider, A is a base spider, B has a special procedure, so want to call A.test() after B.test(). Have to change class B, it difficult to modify Scrapy’s source code.

```
class B(A):
    def test_again(self):
        return super(B,self).test()

    def test(self):
        print 'in class B'
        return Process(self, callback=self.test_again)
```

Comment: You can't, not by only storing the name of the function. Why not store the function reference itself instead?

Comment: And why are you overriding the method in the first place, if you wanted to call the original in the callback? You could just add another method that calls the original overridden method, then use that as the callback, but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not by only storing the name of the function. There isn't enough context there to distinguish between the original method and the override.

You'd either need to store the original method (e.g. not reach in and grab the original function) or pass in a *different* method that uses `super()` to call the original:

```
def original_test(self):
    return super(B, self).test()
```

`super()` isn't limited to just the current method, after all.

Note that the method object `.__name__` attribute will always return the wrapped function object `.__name__` attribute, no need to unwrap the method just to get to that value.

Comment: You can then just use `B.test()` and call `A.test()` from there; the `super()` call does not need to be the first thing you call.